# how to find current month of last year in amazon athena query?

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

for example, If today is 2023-09-23 (yyyymm)
then I need to extract data from 2022 september to 2023 september (2022-09-01 to 2023-09-30).

FOR BELOW CODE, My intention was to print data from 2022 december-01 to Today.
the Query runs, But for some reason, it prints the data from 2022 January-01 instead.
Can you fix the First sentence?

```sql
WITH START_DAY AS (SELECT CAST(date_trunc('month', current_date - interval '14' month) AS VARCHAR) AS START_DAY),
     Current_MONTH AS (SELECT TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'yyyymm') AS Current_MONTH),
TABLE1 as(
select
from
WHERE CAST(DATE_FORMAT(CAST(submission_date AS TIMESTAMP), '%Y%m') AS VARCHAR) 
    between (select start_day from start_day) 
        AND (select Current_MONTH from Current_MONTH)
)


SELECT *
from table1
```

Answer (score 0):

TBH it is not very clear why do you expect `current_date - interval '14' month` to give you the same month an year earlier, last time I've checked it was 12 month in the year  To get the same month but in the previous year can do just:

```
select date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '1' year;
```

Which will give you:

```
   _col0    
------------
 2022-12-01
```

The next thing you will need to fix is the time conversions you do. First of all I would recommend to compare dates rather than strings so convert everything to date instead of using like three different conversions which seemingly use different format (try for example running `SELECT CAST(date_trunc('month', current_date - interval '14' month) AS VARCHAR)`). So the final result would be something like:

```sql
select *
from original_table
where CAST(submission_date AS TIMESTAMP)
   between date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '1' year and now()
```

Fully runnable example:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(submission_date) AS (
    VALUES ('2022-12-12 04:20'),
        ('2022-11-30 04:20'),
        ('2022-12-01 00:00')
)

-- sample query
select *
from dataset
where CAST(submission_date AS TIMESTAMP)
   between date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '1' year and now()
```